# In my app I used uicollectionview then how to make difference between two cell same in all iPhone models?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In my app, I used UIcollectionview then how to make difference between two cell same in all iPhone models. and auto layout is turned on I tried many things but the issue is not resolved my app looks perfect on iPhone 5s but It shows more difference between two cells in iPhone 6s and 6s plus.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRnbU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the cell dynamically according to the screen size. I have faced such situation and fixed it. You can try this, might be help you...

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return CGSizeMake(width, height);
}
```

get width and height

```
-(void)getDynamicCellSize {

width = (SCREEN_SIZE.width - 50)/3;
height = (SCREEN_SIZE.height - (135+self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height)-29)/3;
} // 135 means the navigation bar height + segment control (I have in my design) 

CGFloat width, height;// Declare globally
```

Call getDynamicCellSize method in viewWillAppear or didLoad

### OR

Use this code in sizeForItemAtIndexPath method in 'SWIFT'

```
let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
let cellWidth = (CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.frame) - (flowLayout.sectionInset.left + flowLayout.sectionInset.right) - flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing) / 2
return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
```

Happy coding...

Comment: NOT WORKING WITH SWIFT I CONVERTED YOUR OBJ C CODE TO SWIFT BUT NOT WORKING.

Comment: Actually I am not familiar with Swift. Have you converted the code correctly..? It should be same output as previous..?

Comment: HOW TO GET SCREEN_SIZE?

Comment: In your constant class put this #define SCREEN_SIZE ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size), which will reusable throughout the project